# Wire to connect Dell laptop to Dell 23" monitor

Tags: laptop, monitors

I have a 2010 model [Dell SP2309W](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?%3F%7Elt=popup&c=us&cs=22&l=en&s=dfh&sku=320-7641&validate=false&%7Elt=popup&%7Etab=specstab) 23" monitor. I want to know what wire do I need to buy inorder to connect it to my Ubuntu 14.04 [Dell Latitude 3560](https://www.flipkart.com/dell-latitude-core-i3-4th-gen-4-gb-500-gb-hdd-linux-v3540-laptop/p/itmdxgv5p6xc7z2s?pid=COMDXGV5FGBZV4QY&lid=LSTCOMDXGV5FGBZV4QYLPGFKR) laptop. (Online it says 3540 but on my command line is like anjanesh@anjanesh-Latitude-3560:)

This is how the bottom of my monitor is
[image: This is how the bottom of my monitor is]

Comment: An HDMI cable. Your laptop has an hdmi port and the monitor has an hdmi port.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not asking for a computer hardware recommendation. Cable identification is outside the scope of this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ports pictured are:
Left (almost out of picture) - HDMI
Middle - DVI
Right - VGA

Your laptop has HDMI and VGA ports.

Cables usually have the same type of connector on both ends,  but you can get different ones, and there are adapters the can change the connector at one end. So you could use quite a wide variety of cables.

However, the simplest, best quality and most future-proof option would be a standard HDMI cable.

Comment: How does a HDMI port look like in a laptop ? Similar to a USB port ?

Comment: @anjanesh https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/macro-hdmi-port-260nw-52460485.jpg